# default class for an outlook item(specificaly a calendar)

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, winforms-interop

Hi have been reading about form regions for the last week.I finally managed to create a new interacting form using windows controls (i deprecated forms with vbscript).In the end though i have to associate the new seperate form with a specific calendar from c# code...

but let's get to code...This is how i did it using outlook-vbscript forms.(**using ofts**):

```
    private bool CreateCustomCalendar(string registryname, string newCalendarName, string outlookformpathandfilename)
    {

        app = this.Application;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder primaryCalendar = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)
            this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
             (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
        bool needFolder = true;

        if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("RootCalendar :" + primaryCalendar.Name + " found");



            Outlook.MAPIFolder personalCalendar = primaryCalendar
                .Folders.Add(newCalendarName,
                    Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            personalCalendar.Name = newCalendarName;
            if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("Creating Calendar stage1 complete");

            //Access new calendar by its name that has the habit to append this computer only
            bool notfound1 = true; bool notfound2 = true;
            try
            {
                string mName = primaryCalendar.Folders[newCalendarName].Name;
                if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("calendar accesible by name:" + mName);
                notfound1 = false;
            }
            catch (SystemException sex)
            {
                throw;
            }


            Outlook.MAPIFolder setcalendar = primaryCalendar.Folders[newCalendarName];
            if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("calendar is set");
            PublishFormToPersonalFormsLibrary(setcalendar, outlookformpathandfilename, registryname, registryname, registryname, registryname + "version 1.0.0.1", "1.0.0.1", Application);
            if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("Creating Calendar stage2 complete");

            SetFolderDefaultForm_forappointments(setcalendar, "IPM.Appointment." + registryname, newCalendarName);
            if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("Creating Calendar stage3 complete");

        return needFolder;

    }

    void SetFolderDefaultForm_forappointments(Outlook.MAPIFolder fld, string msgClass, string displayname)
    {

        Outlook.PropertyAccessor objPA = fld.PropertyAccessor;
        string strBaseType;
        string strMsg;
        int intLoc;
        bool blnBadForm;
        int i;
        string PR_DEF_POST_MSGCLASS =
          "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x36E5001E";
        string PR_DEF_POST_DISPLAYNAME =
          "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x36E6001E";

        string[] arrSchema = { PR_DEF_POST_MSGCLASS, PR_DEF_POST_DISPLAYNAME };
        string[] arrValues = { msgClass, displayname };
        string[] arrErrors;
        if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("prepared for setting default item");
        try
        {
            objPA = fld.PropertyAccessor;
            objPA.SetProperty(PR_DEF_POST_MSGCLASS, msgClass);
            objPA.SetProperty(PR_DEF_POST_DISPLAYNAME, displayname);
            if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("default folder set");
            //  arrErrors = objPA.SetProperties(arrSchema, arrValues);
        }
        catch (SystemException sex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is catch with system exception : {0}", sex.ToString());
        }


    }


    public void PublishFormToPersonalFormsLibrary(Outlook.MAPIFolder calendarfolder, string oftFilePath, string messageClass, string name, string displayName, string description, string version, Outlook.Application application)
    {
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        string existingVersion = "";

        // try to create an existing Instance of the Form to check the current installed Version
        try
        {
            // create atemplatefolder object
            Outlook.MAPIFolder templateFolder = application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
            if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("templateFolder is set");

            // we add our new object here
            object existingItem = templateFolder.Items.Add(messageClass);
            if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("added form " + messageClass + " as templates");
            // did we installed the form
            if (existingItem != null)
            {
                // yes, we did it before
                // get the formdescription with latebinding
                Type existingItemType = existingItem.GetType();
                Outlook.FormDescription existingFormDescription = (Outlook.FormDescription)existingItemType.InvokeMember("FormDescription", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, existingItem, null);
                if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("formdescription allocated to existingformdescription");

                // get the installed version
                existingVersion = existingFormDescription.Version;

                // discard the temporary item
                object[] args = { Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard };
                existingItemType.InvokeMember("Close", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, existingItem, args);
                if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("GarbageCollection");

            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }

        // if the existing Version is equal, no need for publishing the form
        // if (version == existingVersion) return;

        // check, if the templatefile exists
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(oftFilePath)) throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException("Form template could not be found!", oftFilePath);

        // create the item from TemplateFile
        object item = application.CreateItemFromTemplate(oftFilePath, missing);
        if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("created item from template");
        // get the FormDescription Property using LateBinding
        Type itemType = item.GetType();
        Outlook.FormDescription formDescription = (Outlook.FormDescription)itemType.InvokeMember("FormDescription", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, item, null);

        // Apply some Parameters to the Formdescription
        formDescription.Name = name;
        formDescription.DisplayName = displayName;
        formDescription.Category = "uncategorized";
        formDescription.Comment = description;
        formDescription.Version = version;
        if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("Set custom form and its properties");

        // Publish Form to Personal Froms Library
        //formDescription.PublishForm(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlFormRegistry.olPersonalRegistry );
        formDescription.PublishForm(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlFormRegistry.olFolderRegistry, calendarfolder);
        if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("associating complete");



    }
```

the question is how to do it with form-regions(**using .ofs**)

any solutions\documentation would be welcomed.
Many thnx to the creators of stack-overflow for this great resource and all developers that altruistically contribute to our problems

Comment: a critical factor that could dominate regarding the .ofs - .oft alternative paths would be the option to create two forms for the same calendar.How on earth does that  work?If anyone knows please contribute...thnx

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it!!! the replacement code for outlook.addin item goes like this:

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Outlook.Folder taskList =Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(
   Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks)
   as Outlook.Folder;

        Outlook.TaskItem taskItem = taskList.Items.Add(
          "IPM.Task.twoformMssges") as Outlook.TaskItem;

        taskItem.Subject = "IPM.Task.twoformMssges Created On " +
          System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();

        taskItem.Save();

        Outlook.MAPIFolder primarytaskfolder = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)
          this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
           (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);
        Outlook.MAPIFolder settaskfolder = primarytaskfolder.Folders["testassociation"];
          Outlook.Application app = this.Application;
        string formpropstring= "twotabs";
       // PublishFormToPersonalFormsLibrary(taskItem,settaskfolder, "c:\\" , "IPM.Task.twoformMssges",registryname, registryname,registryname + "version 0.0.0.1", "0.0.0.1", Application);
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        string existingVersion = "";
         try
         {

            if (taskItem != null)
            {

                Type existingItemType = taskItem.GetType();
                Outlook.FormDescription existingFormDescription = (Outlook.FormDescription)existingItemType.InvokeMember("FormDescription", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, taskItem, null);
                //if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("formdescription allocated to existingformdescription");

                // get the installed version
                existingVersion = existingFormDescription.Version;

                // discard the temporary item
                object[] args = { Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard };
                existingItemType.InvokeMember("Close", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, taskItem, args);
                //if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("GarbageCollection");

            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }

        Type itemType = taskItem.GetType();
        Outlook.FormDescription formDescription = (Outlook.FormDescription)itemType.InvokeMember("FormDescription", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, taskItem, null);

        // Apply some Parameters to the Formdescription
        formDescription.Name = formpropstring;
        formDescription.DisplayName = formpropstring;
        formDescription.Category = "uncategorized";
        formDescription.Comment = formpropstring;
        formDescription.Version = "0.0.0.1";

        //formDescription.PublishForm(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlFormRegistry.olPersonalRegistry );
        formDescription.PublishForm(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlFormRegistry.olFolderRegistry, settaskfolder);
        //if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("associating complete");

        Outlook.PropertyAccessor objPA = settaskfolder.PropertyAccessor;
        string strBaseType;
        string strMsg;
        int intLoc;
        bool blnBadForm;
        int i;
        string PR_DEF_POST_MSGCLASS =
          "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x36E5001E";
        string PR_DEF_POST_DISPLAYNAME =
          "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x36E6001E";

        \\string[] arrSchema = { PR_DEF_POST_MSGCLASS, PR_DEF_POST_DISPLAYNAME };
        \\string[] arrValues = { "IPM.Task.twoformMssges" , "testassociation" };
        \\string[] arrErrors;

        try
        {
            objPA = settaskfolder.PropertyAccessor;
            objPA.SetProperty(PR_DEF_POST_MSGCLASS, "IPM.Task.twoformMssges");
            objPA.SetProperty(PR_DEF_POST_DISPLAYNAME, "testassociation");
            //   if (debugmode) writer.WriteToLog("default folder set");
            //  arrErrors = objPA.SetProperties(arrSchema, arrValues);
        }
        catch (SystemException sex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is catch with system exception : {0}", sex.ToString());
        }






    }
```

also required a couple of attributes(code in brackets) needs to be added

```
[Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClass("IPM.Task.twoformMssges")]
[Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionName("FormInVsto20136.msgclassregion1")]
    public partial class msgclassregion1Factory{ blah blah blah ...
```

...and that does the trick

(I now wonder how to differentiate between save and update)

Comment: the two lines described above(before partial class) are actually added when the wizard asks you for the type of formregion.when separate is chosen the result looks like above.(you may add a second form region to a task folder by stating the same custom message("IPM.Task.twoformMssges") in two formregions.If the formregion appears as region within the task window form then a generic attribute(in brackets) states this configuration.also you don't have to assign the messageclass to a folder(task-appointment-mail,etc)because it appears in all folders of the same type(tasks).

Comment: you might have noticed that my problem was about an appointment but the answer is about tasks.That occured because i didn't want to create dummy solutions\trials where my project functions. Anyhow, it's pretty much the same once you retrieve an outlook item in order to define a messageclass...in order to fit the described Q&A into the puzzle you may wish to explore a complte tutorial at : http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1327185